# How to solve Differential Transformation Method (DTM) in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

My problem's two differential equations in the form of DTM are E1 and E2

Parameters are

```
    \[Delta] = 0;
r = 0.04;
s = 2 r;
\[Eta] = 8;


E1 = W[k + 
     2] == (\[Delta] (k + 1)^2 W[
      k + 1])/((\[Delta] + 0.5 + 1/(s^2 \[Eta]^2)) (k + 2) (k + 
       1)) - ((\[Omega]^2/\[CapitalOmega]^2 - (k (k + 1))/2) W[
      k])/((\[Delta] + 0.5 + 1/(s^2 \[Eta]^2)) (k + 2) (k + 
       1)) + ((k + 1) \[Theta][
      k + 1])/((\[Delta] + 0.5 + 1/(s^2 \[Eta]^2)) (k + 2) (k + 1));


 E2 = \[Theta][
k + 2] == -(((\[Eta]^2 r^2 (1 + \[Omega]^2/\[CapitalOmega]^2) - 1/
    s^2) \[Theta][k])/((k + 2) (k + 1))) - (1/s^2 (k + 1) W[k + 1])/((k + 2) (k + 1));
```

and Boundary conditions,

```
\[Theta][0] == 0; W[0] == 0; \[Theta][1] == 0; W[1] == 0;
```

how to solve these type of equation in Mathematica.
Please help me.
I am not getting any out put fromw the above code.

Comment: Could you give a link to more info on the method, and a simple, concrete example problem?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE, Jagannath! I suggest the following: 
1) Take the [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS).   
2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 
3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.